# How to Improve Image Classification when using ML .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, .net-core, image-classification

I have been working on a POC to identify persons based on photos.
I'm using ML .NET and took the following url as a basis
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning

Basically there is a tag for each person, the each tag has around 200 photos of that person, and I want to predict the correct tag for new photos of any of those persons in the trained model.

Currently I have around  photos for each person to train the model.
The thing is that, when doing the prediction, it is almost never accurate.

Here is what I have been testing for both Training and Prediction

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Trains a model based on the images
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trainingIterations">Number of iterations to perform when training</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void TrainModel(int trainingIterations = 5000)
    {
        try
        {
            var workspaceRelativePath = this.ImageClassificationConfiguration.WorkspaceDirectory;
            var assetsRelativePath = this.ImageClassificationConfiguration.TrainingImagesDirectory;

            // You must unzip assets.zip before training
            IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: assetsRelativePath, useFolderNameAsLabel: true);

            IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);

            IDataView shuffledData = mlContext.Data.ShuffleRows(imageData);

            var preprocessingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(
                    inputColumnName: "Label",
                    outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.LoadRawImageBytes(
                    outputColumnName: "Image",
                    imageFolder: assetsRelativePath,
                    inputColumnName: "ImagePath"));

            IDataView preProcessedData = preprocessingPipeline
                                .Fit(shuffledData)
                                .Transform(shuffledData);
            //.Fit(shuffledData)
            //.Transform(shuffledData);

            //TrainTestData trainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: preProcessedData, testFraction: 0.3);
            //TrainTestData validationTestSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainSplit.TestSet);

            //IDataView trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
            //IDataView validationSet = validationTestSplit.TrainSet;
            //IDataView testSet = validationTestSplit.TestSet;

            IDataView trainSet = preProcessedData;
            IDataView validationSet = preProcessedData;

            var classifierOptions = new ImageClassificationTrainer.Options()
            {
                FeatureColumnName = "Image",
                LabelColumnName = "LabelAsKey",
                ValidationSet = validationSet,
                Arch = ImageClassificationTrainer.Architecture.ResnetV250,
                MetricsCallback = (metrics) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(metrics);
                    Logger?.LogInformation(metrics.ToString());
                },
                TestOnTrainSet = false,
                ReuseTrainSetBottleneckCachedValues = false,
                ReuseValidationSetBottleneckCachedValues = false,
                WorkspacePath = workspaceRelativePath,
                Epoch = trainingIterations
            };

            var trainingPipeline = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(classifierOptions)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

            this.TrainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Logger?.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task<ModelOutput> PredictFromImage(string imageFilePath)
    {
        PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> predictionEngine =
            mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(this.TrainedModel);

        ModelInput image = new ModelInput()
        {
            Image = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath),
            ImagePath = imageFilePath
        };

        var result = predictionEngine.Predict(image);
        return result;
    }
```

What I could do in order to improve the accuracy of the predictions?
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Fildor it is image classification I meant to identify the correct tag for a given photo based on photos of the same persons p=from mdoels previosuly trained.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning

Improve the model

If you're not satisfied with the results of your model, you can try to improve its performance by trying some of the following approaches:

- More Data: The more examples a model learns from, the better it performs. Download the full SDNET2018 dataset and use it to train.
- Augment the data: A common technique to add variety to the data is to augment the data by taking an image and applying different transforms (rotate, flip, shift, crop). This adds more varied examples for the model to learn from.
- Train for a longer time: The longer you train, the more tuned the model will be. Increasing the number of epochs may improve the performance of your model.
- Experiment with the hyper-parameters: In addition to the parameters used in this tutorial, other parameters can be tuned to potentially improve performance. Changing the learning rate, which determines the magnitude of updates made to the model after each epoch may improve performance.
- Use a different model architecture: Depending on what your data looks like, the model that can best learn its features may differ. If you're not satisfied with the performance of your model, try changing the architecture.